# how to get nopCommerce mvc editorfor value on button click using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce mvc5,
and i am not getting textbox value in jquery on button click.

code:

```
<div class="inputs">
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, new { }, ":")
  </div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <input id="Submit-button" name="Submit-button" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#Submit-button").click(function () {
    var value =  $("#Code").val();
    alert(value);
  });
</script>
```

It's always returning null value in alert.

Please give me some idea

Comment: What is the html being generated by `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)`?

Comment: html generated <input id="SMSAuthenticationModel_Code" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="SMSAuthenticationModel.Code"> and i have also try using this id "SMSAuthenticationModel_Code". but still not working

Comment: Then it has to be `var value =  $("#SMSAuthenticationModel_Code").val();` but in any case if the html is `... value="" ...` then the value is an empty string. How have you set the value and what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `nopCom` extensions:

```
@Html.FieldIdFor<T, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
```

It's returning string with id field.
In Your example it will be:

```
$("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Code)").val()
```